# Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static [ValidFragment]

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Error:Error: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static [ValidFragment]

```
private boolean checkFreeSpace(String path, long size) {
    long freeSpace = StorageUtil.getAvailableSpaceInBytes(path);
    if (freeSpace <= size) {
```

right there is the probleme>>>  new DialogFragment() {

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says ([Fragment Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment())):

> Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated
>    when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that
>    subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these
>    constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated;
>    instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle)
>    and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().

So i guess you are Extending/Implementing a Fragment Class and Overloading a constructor with parameters.

You can fix it using the setArguments(Bundle) method explained above.